# App not working after changing Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar to Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I watched a tutorial on how to create a custom Toolbar in Android Studio and I saw that I must change  Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar to Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar. I tried to do it and after running an app it showed only a splash screen and then it crashed. Please, someone, help me.

Comment: Please show us your code or the relevant snippet!

Answer (score 2):

Theme.AppCompat.Light.**NoActionBar**, No action bar means tool bar cant be created.

Change NoActionBar to LightActionBar or anything else you prefer. then customise the tool bar as you wish to

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar
```

Instead of Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar

Answer (score 0):

Set Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar in both values/themes.xml and values-night/themes.xml.